# Find hidden element - PHP

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Im trying to get an element using simplehtmldom and i didn't succeeded.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$url = 'https://oload.stream/f/iNzieKbekMM/Perleshje_nga_blloku_i_qelive_99.mp4';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('#streamurl') as $td) {
    echo $td->plaintext;
}
```

In response i get :

> HERE IS THE LINK

In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pZAM.png) there is showing the streamurl

**What im doing wrong and how to obtain the value ?**

Comment: You'll probably find that Javascript is doing most of the work once the page is loaded, so difficult to get this way.

Comment: im not in that scale to use javascript for passing this issue is there something with php what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

The text "HERE IS THE LINK" is a placeholder. It is replaced via JavaScript, but JavaScript is not executed by PHP.

Print the HTML you get from the URL and check if the stream url is already in that string. Then figure out how to fetch that one from the HTML.

Another option would be to use install a JavaScript engine for PHP. For instance:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.v8js.php or
- https://github.com/pinepain/php-v8

The simpler option would be not to use PHP, but http://phantomjs.org instead.